# CSF country block

Tags: cpanel, firewall, whm

I was wondering if its possible to edit an individual accounts firewall?

Currently we block a few countries via CSF to cut down on spam and so on.

But one client would like all countries to see his site.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to exclude one cPanel account from CSF firewall rules. You will have to remove that countries from firewall if you want to enable that for any single account.